# Error Token=NULL al enviar JWT en Header en servidor AWS

Tags: php, ajax, aws, jwt, codeigniter-4

como estan?
estoy intento solucionar el siguiente error:
Intento enviar un Token en una solicitud HTTP a mi servidor AWS pero en la solicitud los datos llegan NULL.

Tengo una API desarrollada en CodeIgniter 4 y publicada en AWS utilizando la plataforma EC2.
Desarrolle una autenticacion en base a JWT, utilizando el pack firebase/php-jwt.

Una vez que el usuario hace Login, el servidor envia un Token, y luego lo utilizo en cada solicitud HTTP para consumir los metodos de mi API.

Cuando prueba por Postman en mi localhost el Token viaja y se valida de forma correcta.
Publique mi proyecto en AWS y resulta que el Token se crea de forma correcta, se envia al cliente y se almacena de forma correcta, pero cuando intento hacer una solicitud el Token llega al servidor con valor NULL.

Buscando y buscando, creo haber llegado a la conclusión de que mi problema es que AWS espera un formato determinado para mi Token pero no logro darme cuenta como implementarlo.

Les doy mas datos:
Del lado del cliente realice una SPA, utilizando AJAX para las solicitudes.
API implementada en Codeigniter 4.
Utilizo el pack de firebase/php-jwt para crear y validar mi Token.

Desde ya, muchas gracias por sus comentarios.
Saludos.

[image: Metodo AJAX para ver usuarios registrados]

[image: Ruta donde se encuentra mi metodo "usuarios" con el filtro AuthFilter aplicado]

[image: Metodo en mi servidor para validar JWT llamado AuthFilter]

[image: Resultado de POSTMAN al intentar ingresar al metodo "usuarios" con filtro AuthFilter]

[image: Prueba desde servidor Localhost]

Comment: Edita la pregunta con el boton [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/554263/edit) y las partes de codigo pegalas en modo texto y con su formato correspondiente, de esta forma se podra copiar y pegar el codigo para poder replicar tu problema.

Comment: prueba con esta solucion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69021772/13880888